# ASCII code cannot be detected

Tags: c++, visual-c++

For the detecting of negative number;

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

string command;
getline(cin,command);

if (command[0] == '-')
        encoder = -1;
```

and for the detecting of point;

```
  else if (command[x] == '.')
        {
            if (detector = 0)
            {
                floater = pow(10, -1 * x);
                detector = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You have typed the wrong word or format.\n";

                return 0;
            }
        }
```

I use the ENU visual studio 2013 in Windows 8.1 K(Korean) Environment.
When I typed '-' in first space or '.' in any space into "command"(string variable),

it just can't detect the - and.

and two sentences are just always ignored and passed.

What did I forget? Please help me.

Comment: What is the value of `command[0]`?

Comment: Paste enough code to allow us to compile the code, give the same input you gave, and replicate the error.

Comment: Please show more context; what is the definition of `x`?

Comment: At least the expression `if  (detector = 0)` is in error.

Comment: Also `floater = pow(10, -1 * x);` is questionable, as if the offset in the string `command` should have any bearing on the emerging real value.

Comment: `getline(cin,command);` is illegal outside of a function. Please post real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted **is not the real code**, but chances are that the omission of a `setlocale` call reflects a similar omission in the real code.

So that's *one* thing to do, add a `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" )` call at the start of `main`.

You should also take care to *trim* (remove undesired whitespace from) your input string, and to check whether there are any characters left after that, at all.

Also, the assignment in

```
if (detector = 0)
```

is most probably a typo.

Liberal use of `const` can help avoid such, and also the (in my opinion misguided, because it reduces readability) practice of writing the constant first in a comparison.

Also, using integers as boolean, instead of the `bool` type, as you apparently do, is ungood practice.